# php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed ?

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

Am trying to connect to my mysql wamp server but am continuously getting

`Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.`

Simple code which am following is :

```
<?php
$servername = "http://192.168.43.17/"; <--- My IP Address
$username = "user";                    <--- Default username 
$password = "YES";                     <--- Default Password

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=android_api", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Android_api is the database name which I created.

Exact error which am getting after running this code is :

[image: Error while running the php file in browser]

I also bought a hosting from namecheap and my ultimate goal is to connect it to the database over there. I think if I change the servername to namecheap server, username/password to cpanel's credential and dbname to database which I create there, it should work. Shouldn't it?

Can anyone please help me in this,am really stuck over here. It's just not happening.

Comment: ...or `localhost` => `$servername = 'localhost';`

Comment: Marc pointed correctly about the servername. I found answer for my second question(written below the picture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely wrong:

```
$servername = "http://192.168.43.17/"; <--- My IP Address
```

That is not your ip address. that's a URL pointing at your ip address. mysql doesn't work with urls. It wants your hostname, e.g. `example.com`, or just your ip:

Try

```
 $servername = "192.168.43.17";
```

instead.

Comment: seems to be a repost of their other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34127523/login-and-registration-in-android-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite using the same syntax.

Comment: Yeah, it's related to same question. But I thought as it's specific to php connection,I can start a new question. Sorry if that's not the case.

Comment: @driftking9987 if you think the question you posted here is NOT the same as your other question, you'll need to let me know "how" it is different. Far as I can tell, you're using the wrong syntax in both of them and just as Marc outlined in his answer and the comment I left under your question. Do that, change it and try it again. You should be making some headway.

Comment: I had previously made a weather app. Udacity's tutorial,in that I used the same API to fetch the weather detail based on city/pincode etc. In that app I never used any database connection,so I assumed that it can be a new question as I am connecting to a database using android app. Again apologies if I made a duplicate question.

Comment: Thanks Fred. Will accept the answer once I get the working solution. I'll also edit the question if I don't get an answer. As am still working on it, i'll like to keep it open for further discussion or help.

Comment: @driftking9987 you're welcome.